# compojure get request when route has binds

Tags: clojure, compojure, luminus

I use to define my routes in composure like this:

`(GET "/home" [req] (home-page req))`

and then I have the whole request object available to use inside my handler.

but now I want to use routes with binds, like:

`(GET "/details/:id" [id] (details-page id))`

in this case, it seems that I have no way to get the request AND the bound arguments at the same time. I tried:

`(GET "/details/:id" [id req] (details-page id req))`

but req comes nil.

is there any way to get the request on routes with bindings?

I want the bindings so I don't have to do things like:

`(GET "/details" [req] (details-page req))` and then have `<a href="/details?id=123">...`

and I need the request to have access to the session and request headers.

any suggestion?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hum... it is not perfect, but I'm going with:

`(GET "/details/:id" req (details-page (-> req :params :id) req))`

this snippet works, and solves my problem, but I would love something simpler (DRY).

Answer (score 4):

Compojure's vector-destructuring of bindings is optimized for params and not very flexible, but luckily you can use normal map-based destructuring of the request for the trickier cases:

```
(GET "/details/:id" {:keys [id] :params :as req} (details-page id req))
```

Should work.

Comment: That's not a valid map destructuring. Did you forget a level of braces?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Destructuring-Syntax, you should be able bind `req` to the entire request by adding `:as req` to the binding vector:

`(GET "/details/:id" [id :as req] (details-page id req))`